# Applying a function to MySQL export to .txt

Tags: php

I'm exporting some data from MySQL which can be selected through checkboxes on a page to a .txt file.

Now I have a function to "black out" middle digits of the numbers from MySQL, this function is working on my page, there it looks like this:

```
<?php
$sql="SELECT * FROM table";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// Count table rows
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

?>

<?php function blankit($word) {
    return substr($word, 0,2). str_repeat("X",strlen($word)-4) . substr($word, strlen($word)-2,strlen($word));
} 
?>

<?php while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
$code = ($rows['used'] == '') ? blankit($rows['code']) : $rows['code']; ?>
<tr class="first">
<td class="tc"><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><? echo $rows['id']; ?></font></td>
<td class="tc"><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><? echo $code; ?></font></td>

<td><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><? echo $rows['date']; ?></font></td>
<td class="tc"><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><? echo $rows['ip']; ?></font></td>
<td class="tc"><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><? echo $setusedpscde; ?></font></td>
<td class="tc"><input name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" class="checkbox" id="checkbox[]" value="<? echo $rows['id']; ?>"></td> 


</tr>
<?php
}
?>
```

Now I want to apply this same function (blankit) when I export to the .txt file, my export code:

```
    <?php

if ($_POST['exporttxt']) {


for($i=0;$i<count($_POST['checkbox']);$i++){

$export_id = $checkbox[$i];
$text = mysql_query("SELECT code FROM table WHERE id='$export_id'");
$text2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($text);
$text3 = $text2["code"];
$filename = "export";
$filedate = date("Y-m-d");
$fileext = ".txt";
$fileall = $filename.$filedate.$fileext;

 ob_end_clean();
    header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-disposition: attachment;filename=\"$fileall\"");
   header("Content-Type: application/force-download");

    header("Content-Type: application/download");
    header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
    header("Content-Length: ".strlen($output).";\n");



echo chunk_split($text3, 16, "\n");

}
}



?>
```

I tried changing

```
$text3 = $text2["code"];
```

to

```
$text3 = ($text2['used'] == '') ? blankit($text2['code']) : $text2['code'];
```

But this X'ed out all the middle digits of every number, even if used was not =''

What do I have to change here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that for 1st query you selected all columns and in 2nd only the code column

```
$text = mysql_query("SELECT code FROM table WHERE id='$export_id'");
```

In that case, `$text2['used'] == ''` is always true as the value is null. You have to add 'used' column

```
$text = mysql_query("SELECT used, code FROM table WHERE id='$export_id'");
```